# Checking for intersection between an area and a set of points with heterogeneous geographical data

Tags: gps, osmdroid, geography, gpx

I have an application which deals with geographical data and, in particular, tracks. Given an area (radius around geopoint, or bounding box of geopoints) I need to find, among of all these tracks, the ones that have points that interesect with said area.

For the tracks, it seems I will be dealing both with EPSG:3857  and EPSG:4326: they are either inputted by map interaction (openstreetmap, which uses EGPS:4326 data but EGPS:3857 for tiles) or GPS data (which is EGPS:4326). As for the area, I have "blank slate", but I think it will come in both forms (user either indicates an area on the map or provides an address and radius. address would be resolved with the android geocoder, which I am assuming uses EGPS:4326.)

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: It depends on the tools you need. For sure you need to know the datum and coordinate reference (in short: what it is the meaning of latitude and longitude), if you use GPS probably you are dealing with WGS84, if you have national data, you should find out what reference they use. And then, it depends on the tool do you use. Often we use GIS tools, because working with spheroid is prone to many errors.

Comment: Edited with additional info.

Comment: EPSG:4326 is WGS84, so latitude/longitude (warning: some tools requires longitude/latitude). EPSG:3857 is a projection, so you have x, y coordinates. Usually one works with WGS84 (or other lat/long), and it transform to x,y only for display. But it is up to you. Just define a boundary/layers (to reduce confusion), and get all data in the same coordinate systems. If you work with geodetics use lat/long (like long distance plane routes), if you work with direction use y,x (webmercator). Or use libraries. proj4 is commonly used to transform coordinates (also several time within same app)

Comment: So, if I were to use EPSG:3857 for everything I would be able to use "regular" calculations with no conversions, right? Just a regular formula to check if a point is in a circle. But does that mean I would lose accuracy on GPS data? It wouldn't be a big deal if it wasn't noticeable. If I use EPSG:4326 I assume things would get more complex? Excuse my ignorance but I am completely new to the topic.

Comment: The problem is "what is a circle or a line?" If you do for small regions (or if you do not care about precision): yes, you can use Euclidean geometry. Else (e.g. continental data: circles are not much representative (not "equidistant"). People just convert forth and back coordinates. We have proj4 (which is available on many languages, and it is included on most tools). We have various libraries (depending on language) to calculate areas, directions, etc. So which CRS isn't so important (but keep track, do not mix them involuntarily).